# const char* wrong behavior in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qstring, qmap

I have a problem with returning a `const char*` from two functions from a class, by some reason the first value is a replica of the second value or some values is wrong, but both values returned are from different pointers, in this case two `QMap`, the following is the code of the two functions:

```
const char* SomeClass::getSignal(QString signalName)
{
    QString signalsignature = this->signals.value(signalName);
    signalsignature.prepend(QString::number(QSIGNAL_CODE));
    QByteArray ba = signalsignature.toLatin1(); // i try toUTF8 and to Local8Bit
    const char* signalformated = ba.constData();
    return signalformated;
}

const char* SomeClass::getSlot(QString slotName)
{
    QString slotsignature = this->slots.value(slotName);
    slotsignature.prepend(QString::number(QSLOT_CODE));
    QByteArray ba = slotsignature.toLatin1();
    const char* slotformated = ba.constData();
    return slotformated;
}
```

The `this->slot` and the `this->signals` are `QMap<QString, QString>` that save slots and signals signatures ( `somesignal(int)` or `someslot(bool)` with keys `somesignal`, `someslot` respectively).

The class that i use is loaded from a DLL by `QLibrary` using an interface, all works fine using other functions from it, but using these functions like this:

```
const char* signal = someclassinstance->getSignal(tr("clicked"));
const char* slot = someclassinstance->getSlot(tr("onclicked"));

cout << "connecting signal " << signal << " to slot " << slot << endl;
```

this show me:

```
connecting signal clicked to slot rc
```

and the error when i use QObject::connect

```
Object::connect: Use the SLOT or SIGNAL macro to connect NovaRadioButton:: rc
```

I fill the `QMap`s is some function with:

```
signals.insert(methodname,QString(metamethod.signature()));
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong or if maybe is a bug in Qt functions from `QString`, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your functions exit, the `ba` objects are destroyed. The pointers you return point inside memory locations of no longer existing objects. This is the basic (and well known) error of returning pointers to locals:

```
char* foo()
{
    char c = 'a';
    return &c;
}
```

The fact that you're dealing with a QByteArray doesn't matter; it's still an automatic, local variable and thus gets destroyed on function exit.

You should instead return a QByteArray directly, not a `char*`. This is still efficient, since QByteArray uses [implicit sharing](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/implicit-sharing.html).

Comment: Thanks that is, but is not another way? i return const char* because i use it for the QObject::connect(QObject* emiter,const char* signal,QObject* receiver, const char* slot); so what i want is simulate the SIGNAL and SLOT macros in functions, or if there is another way, i know that i can return a QByteArray and use .data() but i want simulate an SIGNAL and SLOT macro if posible.

Comment: @DiegoFernandoMurilloValenci Too complicated to answer in a comment. Post a new question for that :)

Comment: Yeah, i did it, thanks [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485841/how-to-implement-the-macros-signal-and-slot-as-functions-qt)

Answer (score 2):

No bug, you are returning a pointer to the internals of an object that has been destroyed.

Rewrite your functions like this

```
QByteArray SomeClass::getSignal(QString signalName)
{
    QString signalsignature = this->signals.value(signalName);
    signalsignature.prepend(QString::number(QSIGNAL_CODE));
    return signalsignature.toLatin1(); // i try toUTF8 and to Local8Bit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`QByteArray` should be preferred to `char*`. From the Qt docs

> The QByteArray class provides an array of bytes.
>
> QByteArray can be used to store both raw bytes (including '\0's) and
>   traditional 8-bit '\0'-terminated strings. Using QByteArray is much
>   more convenient than using const char *. Behind the scenes, it always
>   ensures that the data is followed by a '\0' terminator, and uses
>   implicit sharing (copy-on-write) to reduce memory usage and avoid
>   needless copying of data.